# Xero Reports: Profit and Loss tracking ID's filter

Tags: xero-api

The Reports/ProfitAndLoss endpoint lets you specify a tracking category ID to filter by. Is there an option to get a PL for those transactions WITHOUT a tracking ID only?

Thanks.

Comment: In the documentation it suggests that some fields should be checked to see that they are not null, which implies that you could check to see if it _is_ null for your purpose. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses

Comment: Thanks. I have played with the where clause (e.g trackingCategoryID==null) and doesn't error, just doesn't return expected results. In Xero itself if you run a PL report you have an option to filter on 'Unassigned' tracking. I just need to find the magic combo for the API

Comment: Maybe email them directly on api@support.xero.com

Comment: I found this which sums up my question perfectly and have taken it up with Xero https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/12339072